# Two triangles are inscribed in conic iff their edges are tangent to another conic.

Tags: projective-geometry

In the list of recomended problems for my course "Projective Algebraic Geometry" I found following problem:

> Prove that two triangles are inscribed in some conic $C_1$ $\iff$ their edges are tangents of another conic $C_2$ .

All geometry is over field $char \neq 2$. Any ideas how it can be proved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$ be the two triangles inscribed in the same conic.
Consider the exagon $ABCC'B'A'$: by [Pascal's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem) the three points
\begin{align}
AB&\cap C'B'& BC&\cap B'A'& CC'&\cap A'A&
\end{align}
lie on a straight line.

Now, let $a=BC$, $b=AC$, $c=AB$ and $a'=B'C'$, $b'=A'C'$, $c'=A'B'$ be the edges of our triangles and consider the exagon whose edges are $a,b,c,a',b',c'$.
The three lines containing the three pairs of opposite vertex are
\begin{align}
(a\cap b)(a'\cap b')&=CC'\\
(b\cap c)(b'\cap c')&=AA'\\
(c\cap a')(c'\cap a)&=(AB\cap B'C')(A'B'\cap BC)
\end{align}
and they meets at a point.
By [Brianchon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianchon%27s_theorem) $a,b,c,a',b',c'$ are tangent to a conic.

Comment: Can we apply Brianchon's theorem if our conic is singular?

Comment: Yes, Brianchon's theorem holds for also degenerate conic.