# Showing that the vertices of two self-polar triangles with respect to a conic are in general position

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I am reading up posts on projective geometry, and I came across [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565048/vertices-of-two-triangles-self-polar-with-respect-to-one-conic-lie-on-another) talking about self-polar triangles with respect to a conic. I am trying to prove that the vertices of two self-polar triangles are in general position. I do not understand the part of his proof where he says

> neither three points from A,B,C,P,Q,R are colinear.

Could someone explain me why this is the case? For example, why could not $A$, $B$ and $P$ be colinear? I tried to prove by contradiction (assuming that $A,B,P$ are colinear and trying to come to a contradiction), but I am not able to.

(I would have commented on his post, but I do not have enough reputation...)

Thank you.

**Edit:** I actually think it is wrong. (If now *I* am wrong, please tell me). Here is an illustration on Geogebra.[image]

The triangles $DEF$ and $GHI$ are self-polar with respect to the ellipse, but they are not in general position.

I would love to have some feedback on my craziness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. There's nothing to stop 3 points from being collinear, but in that case the six points will lie on a degenerate conic. The statement to be proven did not stipulate that they had to lie on a non-degenerate conic.  I've upvoted your question, which should give you enough reputation to comment on the other post.